# Traducciones en la vista de revisión

Tags: bug

Señores, al parecer todavía hay unos temas pendientes con respecto a la traducción en el cálculo de los tiempos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si hay algo que se puede hacer para ayudar agradecería puedan indicarlo aunque asumo que este tipo de cálculos se realiza con librerías externas y que deben tener su propia forma de modificar el `i18n`.

Comment: no podemos hacer nada, son [cadenas ninja](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/60/25) :)

Comment: ya veo, pues ni modo T_T